# Building error of INET of Artery (ITS-G5 V2X): /bin/sh: 1: python: not found

Tags: python, omnet++, inet

My machine environments are as follows:
Linux: Ubuntu 18.04.1
OMNEST: 5.4.1
INET: provided version (maybe v3.6.4) at https://github.com/riebl/artery.git

I executed command `make inet` in the root directory of Artery (as a guild provided). Then the following errors were found:

> cd extern/inet; python inet_featuretool repair
>   **/bin/sh: 1: python: not found**
>   Makefile:18: recipe for target 'extern/inet/.oppfeaturestate' failed make: ***
>   [extern/inet/.oppfeaturestate] Error 127

Is there someone who suffered from this error when installing INET of Artery?
or if there is some who is expert of INET or Artery, please give me a comment to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Your system does not have a `python` executable. Make sure that the default python is set to python2:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 100
```